# testing child component ngOnChanges in angular jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to write unit test for angular child having ngOnChanges @Input. i used approach in this post   [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@christophkrautz/testing-ngonchanges-in-angular-components-bbb3b4650ee8)

My code is below.

```
import { Component, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';    
import { ShipmentCardComponent } from './shipment-card.component';    

@Component({
  template: `<nfx-shipment-card [shipmentData]="{}" [index]="index"></nfx-shipment-card>`,
})
export class TestWrapperComponent {
  shipmentData: any;
  index: number;
}

describe('ShipmentCardComponent', () => {
  let component: TestWrapperComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestWrapperComponent>;
  let element: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ShipmentCardComponent,
        TestWrapperComponent,
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestWrapperComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should trigger lifecycle hooks', () => {

    component.index = 0;
    component.shipmentData = {};

    fixture.detectChanges();
    
  });

  it('should trigger toggle', () => {
    component.index = 0;
    component.shipmentData = {};
    fixture.detectChanges();

    element.toggle();
  });

});
```

No my question is that in my child `nfx-shipment-card` component, I have `toggle` method,  how can i invoke it?

Comment: Your TestWrapperComponent needs a reference to it, so add `@ViewChild()` reference to it, and then you can invoke the toggle method like `component.nfxShipmentCard.toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `By` selector and select `nfx-shipment-card`.

1.) Grab a reference to it using `By.directive` in `beforeEach`

2.) Invoke the toggle method.

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
......
describe('ShipmentCardComponent', () => {
  let component: TestWrapperComponent;
  let shipmentCard: ShipmentCardComponent; // add this line
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestWrapperComponent>;
  let element: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ShipmentCardComponent,
        TestWrapperComponent,
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestWrapperComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    shipmentCard = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ShipmentCardComponent)).componentInstance;
     // add the line above to have access to the element
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should trigger lifecycle hooks', () => {

    component.index = 0;
    component.shipmentData = {};

    fixture.detectChanges();
    
  });

  it('should trigger toggle', () => {
    component.index = 0;
    component.shipmentData = {};
    fixture.detectChanges();

    element.toggle();
    shipmentCard.toggle(); // you should have access to its public methods and properties like so.

  });

});
```